# "No SSISDB available in this SQL Server" - SSIS Deploy Task

Tags: sql-server, azure-devops, ssis, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

When deploying an SSIS package we are encountering the following error "No SSISDB available in this SQL Server".

The package is being deployed via an Azure DevOps release pipeline, using the 'SSIS Deploy' task which is a part of this pipeline toolkit: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SSIS.ssis-devops-tools.

Comment: I have opened a new Q/A for this as there were literally 0 posts about this issue on the internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have experienced this error with two separate fixes:

Ensure that the target SSISDB catalog has been created, if not you can use the [Azure DevOps SSIS Catalog Configuration Task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/devops/ssis-devops-overview?view=sql-server-ver15#ssis-catalog-configuration-task).

If the catalog has been created ensure that the account your deployment agent has been installed under has a security object and permissions on the target SQL server.

To find the user account of the agent, open the services.msc application and go to the properties of the service.

Note: The ambiguity of this error suggests that any number of behaviours could be happening on it - good luck and apologies if these fixes do not help.

Comment: @LeoLiu-MSFT the above answer has been edited - perhaps this is of help to your team?